TypeError: regplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hue'
how can i color the points by treatment_code?
seaborn tutorials use hue but seem it doesn't work any more. pls
g = sns.FacetGrid(filtered_data_few2, col="geneID", col_wrap=2)
g.map_dataframe(sns.regplot, x="fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2", y="log_RPKM", hue="treatment_code")
g.set_axis_labels("fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2", "log_RPKM")
g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}")
g.fig.suptitle("Checking Data Integrity") 
g.savefig("check_XY_data_integrity_facets.png") 

pls see attached data
filtered_data_few2.to_dict()
{'geneID': {47615: 'ENSMUSG00000033845.13', 47616: 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14', 71441: 'ENSMUSG00000033845.13', 71442: 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14', 83357: 'ENSMUSG00000033845.13', 83358: 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14', 95246: 'ENSMUSG00000033845.13', 95247: 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14', 107115: 'ENSMUSG00000033845.13', 107116: 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14', 178497: 'ENSMUSG00000033845.13', 178498: 'ENSMUSG00000025903.14'}, 'geneID_Code': {47615: 6424, 47616: 3634, 71441: 6424, 71442: 3634, 83357: 6424, 83358: 3634, 95246: 6424, 95247: 3634, 107115: 6424, 107116: 3634, 178497: 6424, 178498: 3634}, 'treatment_code': {47615: 0, 47616: 0, 71441: 0, 71442: 0, 83357: 1, 83358: 1, 95246: 1, 95247: 1, 107115: 1, 107116: 1, 178497: 0, 178498: 0}, 'subjectCode': {47615: 2, 47616: 2, 71441: 0, 71442: 0, 83357: 5, 83358: 5, 95246: 4, 95247: 4, 107115: 3, 107116: 3, 178497: 1, 178498: 1}, 'fraction_modified_entropy_in_log2': {47615: 3.37923327856133, 47616: 3.53812826694422, 71441: 3.4466994219982, 71442: 3.42171717668167, 83357: 3.22201990171586, 83358: 3.15946869175788, 95246: 3.7316394955949, 95247: 3.51174645246491, 107115: 3.27035866284374, 107116: 3.55127069700653, 178497: 3.78724847494418, 178498: 1.0}, 'log_RPKM': {47615: 3.73816670405211, 47616: 3.21810806772446, 71441: 3.53277241130615, 71442: 3.15281173913521, 83357: 3.76268765715958, 83358: 3.12973696471841, 95246: 3.57397287316557, 95247: 3.00344543392676, 107115: 3.69757309143792, 107116: 3.00202511808302, 178497: 3.70421288067494, 178498: 3.17510965192311}}


sns.regplot doesn't support hue. See here for a possible alternative. Did you consider sns.lmplot, which does support hue?
